# Is it possible to get an input's value using xpath to search on the value of corresponding label?

Tags: ruby, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Given this HTML markup:

```
<tr>
  <td class="label">Description</td>
  <td class="data"><div>QA Test Customer</div></td>
</tr>
```

Trying to write a Ruby method that will take two parameters "Description" and "QA Test Customer" and assert that the value of the input with the label "Description" is in fact "QA Test Customer" using Selenium WebDriver and XPath.

No familiarity with xpath and so I'm struggling. I know I need an xpath string that will:

```
"find a <td> with class of 'label' that has a value of 'Description' then get the value of the <div> embedded in the following <td> with class of 'data'
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//td[@class='label' and .='Description']/following-sibling::td[@class='data']/div
```

Comment: to elaborate on wst's answer, `.='Description'` could also be written `text()='Description'` The `.` here is called the context node, or the node with the index

Comment: I'm SURE I'm doing something wrong...but I can't make that xpath query work. Any ideas?

Comment: @DangerAngell If you can add a larger code snippet to your question to demonstrate how this is being called, that would help determine the problem. I don't think it's xpath-related.

Answer (score 1):

This is written for Nokogiri. I don't know if Selenium uses Nokogiri, or its own XML parser, so it might not help....

I prefer CSS because it's generally less verbose and easier to understand:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<tr>
  <td class="label">Description</td>
  <td class="data"><div>QA Test Customer</div></td>
</tr>
EOT

doc.at('td.label + td.data').text
=> "QA Test Customer"

doc.at('td.label + td.data').text == 'QA Test Customer'
=> true
```

That's just looking for the first `<td class="label">` followed by its sibling with `<td class="data">`, but we can add in searches for the text too:

```
!!doc.at(%Q/td[class="label"]:contains("Description") + td[class="data"] div:contains("QA Test Customer")/)
=> true
```

Turning that into a method you can call becomes:

```
def td_match(doc, s1, s2)
  !!doc.at(%Q/td[class="label"]:contains("#{ s1 }") + td[class="data"] div:contains("#{ s2 }")/)
end
```

And calling it in IRB:

```
irb(main):024:0> def td_match(doc, s1, s2)
irb(main):025:1>     !!doc.at(%Q/td[class="label"]:contains("#{ s1 }") + td[class="data"] div:contains("#{ s2 }")/)
irb(main):026:1>   end
=> nil
irb(main):027:0> td_match(doc, 'Description', 'QA Test Customer')
=> true
```

Cleaning it up a bit:

```
def td_match(doc, s1, s2)
  !!doc.at(
    %Q/td[class="label"]:contains("#{ s1 }") + td[class="data"] div:contains("#{ s2 }")/
  )
end
```

Or, by adding it to Nokogiri::HTML::Document:

```
class Nokogiri::HTML::Document
  def td_match(s1, s2)
    !!self.at(
      %Q/td[class="label"]:contains("#{ s1 }") + td[class="data"] div:contains("#{ s2 }")/
    )
  end
end

doc.td_match('Description', 'QA Test Customer')
=> true
```

Comment: Nice work Tin Man. I've used Nokogiri in another project to do a little screenscraping and had considered it. Given that you've thrown me a softball I'm all over doing it this way!!

Comment: Got as far as doc.at('td.label + td.data').text in your first simple example and I'm getting "undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)". Seems odd as we are passing in HTML so we know doc is not nil...

Comment: It's not that `doc` is nil, it's that the accessor isn't finding the tags with those classes next to each other. As a result, Nokogiri returns `nil`, and `nil.text` isn't a defined method. Perhaps the sample HTML wasn't an accurate depiction of the real HTML?